# UnicodeDecodeError when running ubuntu-support-status

Tags: 12.04

I had a problem during update 12.04 and asked the question yesterday.I tried the suggested solutions. Now I got the following message (update problem still remains):

```
thomas@thomas-Satellite-P200:~$ ubuntu-support-status
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 79, in help=_("Show unsupported packages on this machine").decode(enc)) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Any ideas?

Edit:

The topic yesterday was: Problem after updating 12.o4

Answer was to try one of the solutions of:

"How do I fix a “Problem with MergeList” or “status file could not be parsed” error when trying to do an update?"

I tried that and came up with the above file.

@ Florian Diesch:

"locale" created the following file:

```
thomas@thomas-Satellite-P200:~$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What question? What solutions? We can't help unless you tell us what you tried.

Comment: Please add the output of `locale` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you have the environment varable `$LANGUAGE` set to `de_DE:en` programs (like `ubuntu-support-status`) will use German messages if possible. But as `$LC_CTYPE` is set to `C` they will assume ASCII character encoding. This leads to errors with messages containing umlauts and other non-ASCII characters.

If you want messages in English set `$LANGUAGE` to `C`. Otherwise set `$LC_CTYPE` to `de_DE.UTF-8` (or some other UTF-8 locale).